# Configurable Object to Object map Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, objectmapper

I haven't been able to find any good examples, or a direction to go for this.  But essentially I want to be able to create a configurable object to object mapping interface.  I don't want to hardcode the fields that should be mapped to one another, but rather give users an interface to be able to say fieldA from objectA maps to fieldB from objectB.

These configuration settings can be persisted in SQL, or an XML file, doesn't really matter to me.  This is a Spring Boot application.

I was using Orika for the mapping currently, but I don't know how to make it configurable.  Am I on the right track, or does it not have that capability?  Would a CustomMapper be what I need to do?  Looking for some good examples, or the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) a try. It provides full automation of mapping process and allows handling of complicated mapping cases. Usually, all this flexibility comes at a price of reduced performance, but is maybe good enough in your case.

Mappings are usually set using XML files. In later versions, Dozer also supports mappings via API and via Annotations. Check their website for more info. Dozer also has a [Spring framework integration](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/springintegration.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I'll certainly review.  I looked at it briefly before, and I'm not sure how I would be able to load mappings on the fly?  I could alter the XML, but I'd have to refresh the singleton instances of the mapperfactory I assume?  Mapping through the API is no good, because I have to hardcode the maps.  I want to be able to store the mappings in a datastore and edit them, and have the mapperfactory refresh from there.  Any ideas?  I just don't know enough about it yet.

Comment: Dozer API mappings are created in order to solve various XML mapping flaws and one of those is dynamic mapping. See this post, maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741567/bean-mapping-using-dynamic-mapping